# Define org-agenda-files relative to org-directory?

Tags: org-agenda, config

I'm trying to set up my config so that the `org-agenda-files` are defined in relation to the `org-directory`.

Right now, I use all of the files in my `org-directory` as agenda files. In my config is:

```
(setq org-agenda-files (directory-files-recursively org-directory "\\.org$"))
```

This works flawlessly for that; however, I'm looking to reduce the number of files included in my agenda to only those in the "agenda" subdirectory within `org-directory`. I want it to be something like `(setq org-agenda-files (org-directory + /agenda/))`, but I don't know lisp well enough to figure it out.

Comment: `(directory-files-recursively  (concat org-directory "/agenda/") ....)` will look in the `agenda` subdirectory of `org-directory`.